# Android development - Bluetooth embedded system PIN

Tags: android, authentication, bluetooth, connection, embedded

I need some help here. I need to connect via Bluetooth to a hardware device that communicates with Bluetooth. I have no control on the device (that is more than 5 years old). I have already some working code, but the problem is that the system ask for a PIN and I have no idea what the PIN of the device is. People who have built the system have no idea either. At the moment they are using an old HP iPaq to connect (also 5 years old).

Anyone has any idea how to solve the problem? How to find the PIN or set a new one?

Thanks,
Umberto

Answer (score 0):

Based on checking several BT devices...

Try 0000. Often the default. Other default is 1234

Comment: Thanks. I should have mentioned that I already tried: 0000, 1234 the serial number, the name, 000000 and 123456. Connection refused. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

Just for info I got the solution. For old embedded devices you need to create an "insecure" connection

device.createInsecureRfcommSocket(DEV_UUID);

This does not require a PIN. The connectino works perfectly.

-- Umberto